# Sitecore 8.2 could Translate.Text run in controller code or should it run while rendering views?

Tags: multilingual

I want to run the Sitecore command Translate.Text inside a controller, which doesn't seem to translate (at that time). I've tried debugging and also run different Translate commands (like Translate.TextByDomain) in VS2015's Immediate window. When I continue the debugger after returning the View, the Immediate window can translate text. Does this mean that Translate.Text() only works after a certain point? Does it need some Context?
The translation fails at Documenthelper class while returning value from method MakeNameForMonthlyReports.

Controller (stripped):

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var viewmodel = new DocumentsViewModel(); 
    //attention, there's Documents~ and Document~ ViewModel in this code sample.
    var val = "ABC";
    Parallel.Invoke(
            () => { viewmodel.MonthlyDocuments = DocumentHelper.GetMonthlyReports(val, Items.Fields.Reporting, _service); },
            () => { viewmodel.QuarterlyDocuments = DocumentHelper.GetQuarterlyReports(val, Items.Fields.Reporting, _service); }
            //stripped 4 more calls
    );
    return View("~/Views/Index.cshtml", viewmodel);
}
```

Documenthelper class (stripped) :

```
public static List<DocumentViewModel> GetMonthlyReports(string val, string category, IService _service) //IService not the real name, just renamed for brevity.
{
    var result = new List<DocumentViewModel>();
    try
    {
        var response = _service.GetMonthlyReports(val, category);
        response = response.Where(t => ((t.Year.Value == DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1).Year) && (t.Month.Value >= DateTime.Now.Month)) || ((t.Year.Value == DateTime.Now.Year) && (t.Month.Value <= DateTime.Now.Month)))
             .OrderByDescending(t => t.Year.Value)
             .ThenByDescending(t => t.Month.Value)
             .ToList();
        foreach (var item in response)
        {
            var dvm = new DocumentViewModel()
            {
                LastChanged = item.LastImportDate,
                Name = MakeNameForMonthlyReports(item.FileName),
                Url = GetDocumentUrl(item.FileName)
            };
            result.Add(dvm);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Error(ex.Message, ex);
    }
    return result;
}

private static string MakeNameForMonthlyReports(string filename)
{
    string[] fileTags = filename.Split('_');
    string monthToTranslate = string.Empty;
    switch (Convert.ToInt32(fileTags[3]))
    {
        case 1:
            monthToTranslate = "Global.Library.DateSettings.Month.January";
            break;
        case 2:
            monthToTranslate = "Global.Library.DateSettings.Month.February";
            break;
        case 3:
            monthToTranslate = "Global.Library.DateSettings.Month.March";
            break;
        //case 4 etcetera
    }
    return $"{SC.Globalization.Translate.Text(monthToTranslate)} {fileTags[2]} {fileTags[1]}.pdf";
}
```

After being outside the Parallel.Invoke command while debugging, the text translation seem to work.

While writing this question, this makes sense as the context is not passed into the parallel tasks, but how can I make the context available (without running into unexpected behavior)?
Some might think, why use Parallel.Invoke anyway? I'm lazy on this one, and don't want to rewrite the called _service object to work asynchronously, but I do want to speed up these 6 calls to _service.

New insights: one of the parallel tasks seem to have Context. It can translate correctly while debugging on one of the threads being run by Parallel.Invoke. I didn't see this until now, as not all tasks returning documents, yet. It can't on other threads. This seem to be a Thread thingie...

Another addition: I'm using DictionaryDomain in my multi site solution.

Comment: Can you try creating a variable `var language = Sitecore.Context.Language` before Parallel and then use `Translate.TextByLanguage(string key, Language language)` instead of `Translate.Text`?

Comment: @Marek Musielak: That works, before Parallel indeed.

Comment: Comment converted to an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `Sitecore.Context` inside `Parallel.Invoke`. And `Sitecore.Context` is used in `Translate` methods. That's why you need to pass all the necessary data to the method. Try:

1. Create variables

```
var language = Sitecore.Context.Language;
var database = Sitecore.Context.ContentDatabase ?? Sitecore.Context.Database;
```

before `Parallel.Invoke`.

2. Use

```
 Translate.TextByLanguage(null, new TranslateOptions {Database = database}, key, language, key);
```

instead of `Translate.Text`.

Comment: Do you mean i should pass the language to the documenthelper class? I'll try this right away.

Comment: Not working unfortunaly. It seems it can't find the dictionary itself while running some of the threads created while doing Parellel.Invoke. Also running Translate.TextByDomain is not working at the same time.

Comment: Answer edited. This should do the trick.

Comment: Marek, +1 you nailed it -almost-, thanks :)
Didn't tell you, but I'm using domain dictionary in my (multi) site, so had to replace null with my Dictionary domain. Added line above Parellel.Invoke: var dom = Sitecore.Context.Site.DictionaryDomain;